# Count and select first row by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2), desc = c("a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "b3"))
```

I would like to count by id and select the first row of desc within each id group. That is, return a data frame like the following.

```
id count desc
1  2     a1
2  3     b1
```

Is there an easy way to do it using dplyr package? Can pipes + `group_by()` + `summarise()` do the work without using `filter()` and `join()`?

Stata can do it as:

```
collapse (count) count=id (first) desc, by(id)
```

Comment: Try `group_by()` + `slice()`

Comment: `df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(count = n()) %>% 
  slice(1)`

Comment: With `data.table`, `setDT(df)[, .(count=.N, first=desc[1]),by=id]` will work.

Comment: Thanks, zx8754, worked perfectly. Rich, thanks too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise(count=n(), desc = first(desc))
#       id count   desc
#      <dbl> <int> <fctr>
#1      1     2     a1
#2      2     3     b1
```